# A small ball got stuck in audio jack, how to get it out?

Tags: lumia, nokia-lumia-1020

By a kid's mistake a ball got stuck inside my phone's audio jack. Jack's shape inside is like narrowing tunnel and ball got jammed in there.

At Nokia service, they are asking for amount almost half the phone's original cost. I am not supposed to give this much.

Any way to get it out?

[image: A small ball is inside this audio jack]

Comment: Is the ball metal? If so, a magnet might be able to pull it out. Alternatively, put some superglue on the tip of a toothpick, push it into the jack against the ball, wait for the glue to dry and (hopefully) pull both the pick and the ball out.

Comment: No @Indrek, Ball is of plastic, A soft plastic that got badly stuck inside. glue trick my ruin connectivity pins inside.

Comment: How soft is the ball? Is it compressed in there? Would a pin piece it?

Comment: a vacuum cleaner?

Answer (score 1):

How about tweezers? Maybe something like [this](http://clasno.com.ua/img/p/full/2400073a.jpg), depending on how deep it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a vacuum cleaner. Put it on its highest power suction, and then put it against the 3.5mm headphone jack. If the ball found its way inside, it means it can come out since the jack is just one size throughout. Try it